# JS не вставляет текст в страницу

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Я реализовываю функцию добавления HTML-разметки в код через функцию js.

Вот она сама:

```
async function get_threads () {
  //получение элемента div(он такой есть)
  const div = document.getElementById("thd");
  //получение данных с веб-сервера в виде матрицы из 3 элементов в каждом вложенном массиве

  const rezultat = await fetch("/threads/1");
  let list = await rezultat.json();
  console.log(list)
  //перебор циклом for
  for (let i = 0 ; i < list.length; i++ ) {
    var arr = list[i]
    console.log(arr[0]);
    console.log(arr[1]);
    console.log(arr[2]);
    //вставляю данные из полученной матрицы как HTML разметку  в контейнер div
    div.innerHTML = div.text + `<div><strong>theme : ${arr[0]}</strong> <p> за авторством ${arr[1]}</p> <a href="${arr[2]}">тык для перехода</a> </div>`;
  }


}
```

Я успешно получаю данные с веб-сервера и нормально их перебираю, однако когда пытаюсь вставить разметку HTML ничего не происходит. В консоли не выводится не каких сообщений. В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: Проверь чему равна вот эта переменная `div = document.getElementById("thd")`.  И проверь вот это `div.text`...